# MVC Codeigniter obj->save() or service->save()

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am using Codeigniter and I am trying to separate the "module"-layer into domain objects and a mapper/service (lets call it service).

In my controller I call the mapper to get a user:

```
$user = service->fetchUser($id);
```

The service then creates a new object of type user and populates it.

```
return = new entities\User($array);
```

When i want to save my object. Shall I do:

```
$user->save();
```

(I think it looks very good) and then from my domain object class call the service.

Or shall I do:

```
$service->save($user);
```

This clearly separates the object class from the CRUD logic but I don't think it looks as good.

Is there any "best practice" or one witch is the absolut correct way?

**Thanks for all help!**

(My first Q at SO so be gentle ;) )

Comment: i would think, you would do $server->saveUser($user) since your getting a user from $service->fetchUser($id), if you wanted to make the saving process attached to the user object, then maybe you would also attach the loading to the user such as $user->load($id)  and $user->save($user), hope this made sense..

Comment: Isn't this counter-intuitive to using the codeigniter framework?

Comment: Dave: I think i stick with $service->save()
Kisaragi: Well, i like CI but it's not perfect.